# using getimagesize to return file type

Tags: php

I've seen this somewhere, but can't seem to remember. How can I use `getimagesize()` to return the file type?

```
$url = (POST_IMAGESELECTOR);
$path_parts = pathinfo($url);
   if ($path_parts !='') {
     $extension = $path_parts['extension'];
     } else {
        $extension = getimagesize($url);
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given [the documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), `getimagesize` return an array of 7 values.

The one you can use are:

> Index 2 is one of the IMAGETYPE_XXX constants indicating the type of the image.

And / Or:

> mime is the correspondant MIME type of the image. This information can be used to deliver images with the correct HTTP Content-type header

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php):

`getimagesize` Returns an array with 7 elements.

> Index 2 is one of the IMAGETYPE_XXX constants indicating the type of
>   the image.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [manual for `getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php). Its return value is an array with the third element indicating the image's type.

Answer (score 0):

Just [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php):

> Returns an array with 7 elements.
>
> ...
>
> **Index 2 is one of the IMAGETYPE_XXX constants indicating the type of the image.**
>
> ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $image = getimagesize('/path/to/image.gif') ;
    $imagetype = $image['mime'];
    echo $imagetype . "<br />";
    print_r($image);
```